# PJSIP app can't register in background on locked phone (iOS8+)

Tags: ios, voip, pjsip

Currently I'm using PJSIP (2.3) on iOS and pjsua_init function works well if phone is not locked (PIN locked).

But if phone is locked and receives silent push notification and tries to re-register pjsua_init function returns 120001 (Operation not permitted). I've tried both TCP and UDP. All the same result.

Any workaround or clarifications appreciated :)

Comment: Maybe you can check the source code in this project: https://github.com/chakrit/gossip to see if there's something you can use. Been using it myself, but still haven't implemented background work.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like I figured it out. I set pjsua log file and this file is not accessible if device is locked. So this caused pjsua fail to initialize. Right after I added NSFileProtectionKey:NSFileProtectionNone to this file everything went well again.

Hope someone might find this useful.